# Error C2420 : illegal symbol in first operand

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2019, masm

I have this code, I am using Visual Studio 2019. Compiler gives the error:
Error   C2420   'less': illegal symbol in first operand

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a, b, c, d, x;
int values[5]; // масив для збереження у(х)
void main() {
a = -6; b = 4; c = 8; d = 2;
__asm {
    mov eax, offset values
    push eax 
    mov cx, 5 
    start: 
        mov ax, 3 
        sub ax, cx 
        cwde 
        mov ebx, eax 
        mov eax, a 
        cmp ebx, 1 
        jl less // if х < 1, go to less
        je equals //if х == 1, go to equals

        // if х > 1:

        imul eax // a^2
        sub eax, ebx // a^2-x
        cdq 
        mov ebx, c 
        idiv ebx // (a^2-x)/c
        jmp result 

    less :
        mov edx, 2
        imul edx // a*2
        imul ebx // a*2*x
        add eax, 5 // a*2*x+5
        jmp result 
    equals :
        mov ebx, b 
        sub eax, ebx // a-b
        cdq 
        mov ebx, d 
        idiv ebx // (a-b)/d
        jmp result 
    result :
        pop ebx 
        mov[ebx], eax 
        add ebx, 4 
        push ebx 
        loop start 
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << values[i] << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

The compiler gives error because of this line:

```
jl less
```

Without it, the code works. But I need this line, how to fix this?

Comment: Try to ditch the `using namespace std`

Comment: Why do you have spaces between some of your labels and the colons? Are you sure that your assembler supports that? Or maybe you have some other symbol named `less` elsewhere in your program?

Comment: `main` returns `int` in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have included the entire `std` namespace into the local namespace by the line:

```
using namespace std;
```

The problem with this is that `std` namespace includes function objects (class templates) [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), [`std::greater_equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal), etc that are used for comparisons.

Since `std::less` has been pulled into the local namespace, the MSVC inline assembly code you have used is confused as it thinks you are trying to `jmp` to the label `less` from the `std` namespace and not the label `less` further in your inline assembly code.

The proper fix is to **remove** this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

It is bad practice to include the entire `std` namespace. Removing the line above will require changing this line:

```
cout << values[i] << endl;
```

to:

```
std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
```

Alternatively you can replace `using namespace std;` with:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

This will only include these two items into the local name space.

Comment: Alternatively, `using std::cout` and `using std::endl` will import single names instead of an entire `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I needed to change less on some other name (less1 for example))

Comment: I believe that means your bug was caused by `using namespace std` as suggested in the first comment to your question.